# resetting admin password without booting

Tags: windows, boot, passwords

I cannot figure out how to reset the admin password on an LG Flatron N1941w. I only have access to the monitor which has the mouse, keyboard and internet ports all attached. I don't have the ability to use USB devices and turning on and off the computer requires Administrator access. Is there any way of bypassing all this and gaining Administrator privileges?

Comment: Sounds like someone set the hardware up this way for a reason. Ask them.

Answer (score 1):

a LG Flatron N1941w is [a thin client](http://networkmonitor.lge.com/).  When you log into your thin client, you are given a limited user account on a remote server.  There is (deliberately) no way for you to gain administrator privileges on the server.  If there was, it would a security problem (known as a privilege escalation vulnerability)

Comment: If you actually the admin on the server too, and you have forgotten your own password, there are ways to reset that but you will require physical access to the server.  It cannot be done using a thin client.

Answer (score -1):

General rule : Unless you reboot the altered/reseted admin password wont get updated with respective to windows os, And whatever the tools which we use to reset the password normally alter some registry values which wont work unless your machine rebooted.

If its your local computer/remotely viewing the screen of client you can try these steps :

1) Download Pstools from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649)

2) Start Command prompt

3) Change the prompt to the PSTools folder by typing the full folder path. Example: C:\vignesh\PSTools

4) Type `pspasswd.exe \\Remote_computer_name -u user_name -p new_password`

You can change the password of local admin,

Command Explanation :

-u  Specifies optional user name for login to remote computer.

-p  Specifies optional password for user name. If you omit this you will be prompted to enter a hidden password.

Note : The above method will work only if you are connecting your machine remotely/your lan computer .

Hope it helps

Comment: This is wrong.  [`-p` is the parameter for the existing password](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897543), which the OP doesn't have.